# Выбор текста из input

Tags: javascript, html, input, выборка, html-form

Хочу сделать скрипт для получения доп.данных пользователя и упростить вставку URL для пользователей. Есть код

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="id" size="33" required>
```

И например пользователь вводит ссылку на страницу:

```
https://vk.com/durov
```

Из этой ссылки мне нужно выбрать **durov**. Как реализовать такое?
Знаю, что это просто, но пока не знаю как :(

Comment: Используй силу регулярных выражений

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev было бы неплохо пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью регулярного выражения вы может отбросить лишнюю часть url страницы:

```js
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var pageId = document.getElementById('pageUrl').value.replace(/^https?\:\/\/vk\.com\/(\w+)\/?/, '$1');
  alert(pageId);
});
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" name="id" size="33" id="pageUrl" required>
<input id="get" value="Получить" type="button" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, а через PHP есть решение?

Comment: `preg_replace('/^https?\:\/\/vk\.com\/(\w+)\/?/', '$1', 'https://vk.com/durov')`

Answer (score 3):

Начать с того, что нужно получить текст из `input`-элемента. Способов очень много, возьмем какой-нибудь простой, я придерживаюсь получения элемента по идентификатору, поэтому добавил бы атрибут идентификатора:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="id" id="myInput" size="33" required>
```

Просто добавил `id="myInput"`, идентификаторы как никак вносят некую уникальность. После чего получу данный элемент и его значение в js-скрипте:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Вот хороший ответ по получению значения текста из `input` с enSO: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/5275890). Текст из поля ввода есть, теперь возьмем то, что нам нужно в этом тексте. Опять же - способов много, если с регулярками не знакомы, то можно старым добрым `substr` и `lastIndexOf`

```
var result = inputValue.substr(inputValue.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Внутри функции `substr` **+1** - для того, чтобы слэш не попал в результат.

```js
function showResult(){
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var result = inputValue.substr(inputValue.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" name="id" id="myInput" size="33" required>
<button onclick="showResult()">Результат</button>
```

Метод [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) возвращает указанное количество символов из строки, начиная с указанной позиции, если второй параметр не указан, то вернет все символы с указанной позиции до конца строки. Метод [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) возвращает индекс последнего вхождения указанного значения в строку.